# W25Q128JVSIM footprint sizes

Tags: pcb, eaglecad

I am trying to make PCB.I am using EAGLE. This is my second PCB design. First was only with pin headers so I am beginner. I searched to W25Q128JVSIM and installed from [here](https://app.ultralibrarian.com/details/374965e2-61a8-11eb-9033-0a34d6323d74/Winbond/W25Q128JVSIM). I searched another sites like componentsearchengine and snapeda but all have same sizes. What I want to ask is, I read data sheet (I share photo for package specifications). In this photo H's max value is 8.10 mm but mine is 8.85 mm. b is 0.48 mm mine is 0.51 mm. There are some changes. Will it be a problem when I make the PCB ? Thank you.
And my chip is [chip](https://www.verical.com/pd/winbond-serial-nor-flash-W25Q128JVSIM-4791257?utm_medium=aggregator&utm_source=findchips&utm_campaign=verical_2021&utm_content=bnl_1%3E)
[image]

[image]

Comment: what does your gut tell you?

Comment: What do you mean I didn't understand "gut" sorry.

Comment: it means `gut feeling`, which means `intuition` or `instinct` .... what does your intuition tell you? ... the IC legs are 0.03 mm wider and 0.37 mm longer

Comment: I am thinking , If everybody do same sizes, then it must be something. I created this question for just to be a sure. I guess 0.03 mm won't be a problem but 0.37mm maybe problem.

Comment: your thinking makes sense

Comment: so what do you suggest? Should I make my own foootprint?

Comment: you could, if you like ... or just be aware of the lengrh when routing traces

Comment: @jsotola I think you may have it backwards -- what the OP is describing is that the IC legs (as per the datasheet) are shorter and narrower than the footprint pads, which is normal.

Answer (score 0):

Footprints are larger than the chip to give some wiggle room during assembly.

Most datasheets will actually give you a separate set of dimensions for the recommended footprint, although this is not the case for your device.

When drawing your own footprints from a datasheet you should use these rather than the physical dimensions of the chip itself.

Comment: Is this footprint okay? I am going to use it then. Thank you.

Comment: @mrneedshelpalot if you want to check the footprint against the datasheet (which is always a good idea), check the pin spacing (dimension e) and generally that the chip fits _inside_ the footprint.

Comment: Thank you. @DamienD

Comment: Some specifics may vary from datasheet to datasheet. The most important thing is the distance between the middle of the pins (pitch). If the distance between pins - both those on the same side and between sides - is correct, then it will be OK (pad width/length may vary a little, won't matter)

Comment: Both 1.27mm. Thank you for your comment.